# How to split textarea rows and push to array in javascript and no jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, newline

I am trying to split each line of multiple user input in textarea and push each line to the array. Somehow the split function isn't working in my code.

Here is the HTML and JavaScript code

```js
function myFunction() {

  var lst = [];
  var t = document.getElementById("myTextarea");
  var split_lines = t.value.split('\n');
  for (var i = 0; i < split_lines.length; i++) {
    document.write(split_lines[i].trim() + "<br/>");
    lst.push(split_lines[i].trim());

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <textarea id="myTextarea" rows="4" cols="5">
            erew 
            qwee. 
            qwqad
          </textarea>
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>

</html>
```

expected result:

```
erew 
<br/>
qwee.
<br/> 
qwqad
```

Comment: It works for me. What makes you think the split isn't working? (Side note: you shouldn't use `document.write` as that overwrites your page.)

Comment: Your text has no line breaks in it so splitting on `\n` doesn't do anything.

Comment: What result are you getting? I tried your code and got your expected result.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to input vertically. I only tried horizontal input  IceMetalPunk, Mark, P and Phil